# When is it okay to use in on one after the other in the same sentence?

Tags: prepositions

I'm watching the Netflix docuseries "Evil Genius: the True Story of ..." and in it, the following sentence has come up two times.

> ... Brian was actually in on the heist.

The first few words of the sentences are different but the last ones are the same. Why are the prepositions *in* & *on* used consecutively here? Isn't using *in* enough to convey the meaning? I looked for an explanation on the web but couldn't find anything helpful. An explanation with some more examples would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Most dictionaries will have an entry for the combination *in on*. You can easily look this up.

Comment: You're absolutely corrent. Looked it up in the dictionary and I found its meaning.

Answer (score 2):

After @Robusto's suggestion, I looked it up in the dictionary and found the meaning.

*in on (Adjective): Part of or privy to (something private, especially a plan or plot).*

Examples:

1. She was *in on* the surprise from the beginning.
2. We had to let him *in on* it after he overheard some of us talking.